# Container is not scaling smaller than 576px

Tags: grid, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a wordpress template with bootstrap 4 and I'm kinda lost. The container isn't scaling down smaller than 576px and I can't figure out why.

Here's a link to the website:

I really don't know where to begin to look for the mistake I'm making, so any idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

after doing some inspecting it looks like your maxmegamenu doesnt have any media query that accounts for any screen sizes smaller than 600px[image: This might be a problem ;)]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was able to set the breakpoint to mobile menu (in the settings of mega menu) to 768px, so it breaks earlier. It didn't help. Even if i give the menu a width of 100px, the site stops scaling down like before. So I guess that wasn't the problem

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. nvm. I had a `min-width:550px` on the html-element in CSS. I don't even know why. Removing that fixed the problem.